# Getting records with timestamp (HHMMSS) over 5 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have a table with these 3 fields

REGDATE - In format YYYYMMDD

REGTIME - In format HHMMSS

REGSTAT - Status which I query

==============

Is it possible using only a query to select records with an open status that are before 5 hours from current time?

So:

Select all "Open" Records that don't have a REGTIME from the last 5 hours

Current Date/Time = 20201125 / 194711

**20201124 / 224011**

**20201125 / 084055**

**20201125 / 121142**

20201125 / 171153 -- under 5 hours ignore

Thanks for any help
20201125 / 181746 -- under 5 hours ignore

Comment: Wait, is your REGTIME column a ```time``` column or ```varchar```/```char```/```int```? This is important to know.. Just for giggles, I'd love to know whether your REGDATE was a ```date``` or ```char``` too.

Comment: Date and time data types don't have "formats", they are binary values. Tables don't have "fields" nor do they have "records", they have columns and rows. If, as well, you need to query your columns as a datetime (rather than a date or time) then it makes more sense to store them as a datetime data type, and if you need the date and time separate have them as separate (`PERSISTED`) computed columns.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your REGDATE is a `date` column, and your REGTIME is a `time` column, then you can add them together to get a `datetime` value for performing your 5 hour calculation.

```sql
select * 
from (
        select 
            regdate, 
            regtime,
            newdatetime = DATEADD(day, 
                            DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATE, '19000101', 112), regdate), 
                            CAST(regtime AS DATETIME2)
                          )
        from @test 
) myNewTable
where newDateTime <= dateadd(hour, -5, '2020-11-25 19:47:11')
```

If they are `char` columns, there is no index seek but you can string concat them after putting in the colons to format your time.

```sql
newdatetime = CAST(CONCAT(regdate, ' ', stuff(stuff(regtime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')) as datetime2)
```

If they are `int` columns, you can either convert them to `char` before you concat them (because those `int` columns won't convert directly into `datetime` properly -- but this will be poor performance), or you can do your datetime calculations entirely in int form, and someone with more caffeine than I will need to give you that example.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell from the leading 0 that the time is not an integer. To make best use of indexes, comparing to the column values is best. I get the datetime for 5 hours ago and extract the date and time parts in formats compatible with the columns.  If your columns are not char(8) and char(6), you should change these to be the same. This will insure that type conversion does not prevent using indexes on REGDATE and REGTIME.

```
declare @now_minus_5 datetime = dateadd(hour, -5, getdate()) -- 5 hours ago
declare @REGDATE_MAX char(8) = CONVERT(char(8), @now_minus_5, 112), -- YYYYMMDD
    @REGTIME_MAX char(6) = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8), @now_minus_5, 108), ':', '') -- HHMMSS

select *
from DataTable
where REGSTAT = 'OPEN' 
    AND (REGDATE < @REGDATE_MAX OR (REGDATE = @REGDATE_MAX AND REGTIME < @REGTIME_MAX))
```

The date and time compare has two parts because you have date and time separate. You only need to check the time if the date is the same date as of 5 hours ago.